# JSR223 Pre Password Encryption database connection errors

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, password-encryption

I'm getting this error whenever I try to run my jmeter script. The website is generating a dynamic encryption code when user is trying to login into the application. It is sent to server along with password and username for authentication. How can I fix this issue?

```
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.coyote.http11] ) JBWEB003028: Start processing with input [txtUserid=PERFUNIADM05&a2=**********&a3=823EUB0OC87JP85DQNFDEE7RJOO0DAQQ&txtpasswd=I+am+an+idiot.&cmbOrgCodes=001&submit=Sign+in&txtResFrac=1920]
```

28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/collections]] ) I am in Timer Filter
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils] Get module name for path /loginAction.do
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils] Module name found: default
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor] Processing a 'POST' for path '/loginAction'
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils] Get module name for path /loginAction.do
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils] Module name found: default
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor] Processing a 'POST' for path '/loginAction'
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string '**********' to class 'java.lang.String'
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string '823EUB0OC87JP85DQNFDEE7RJOO0DAQQ' to class 'java.lang.String'
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string 'I am an idiot.' to class 'java.lang.String'
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string 'PERFUNIADM05' to class 'java.lang.String'
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string '001' to class 'java.lang.String'
28.02.2024 09:33:26,234 DEBUG [org.apache.commons.beanutils.ConvertUtils] Convert string '1920' to class 'java.lang.String'
28.02.2024 09:33:26,266 INFO  [stdout] **** LSObject.getObject() - p_strJNDIName :java:/jdbc/xxxxxxxx
28.02.2024 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr] xxxxx.common.Exceptions.LSException
28.02.2024 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr]  at xxxxx.common.Exceptions.LSExceptionFactory.(LSExceptionFactory.java:26)
28.02.2024 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr]  at xxxxx.common.Utilities.DataBaseConnection.openConnection(DataBaseConnection.java:53)
28.02.2024 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr]  at xxxxx.common.Utilities.DataBaseConnection.getConnection(DataBaseConnection.java:29)
28.02.2024 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr]  at xxxxx.common.ejb.common.SessionBean.getConnection(SessionBean.java:83)
28.02.2024 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr]  at xxxxx.common.ejb.security.LoginEJB.multipleOrg(Unknown Source)
28.02.2024 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
28.02.2024 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
28.02.2024 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
28.02.2024 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 09:33:26,271 ERROR [stderr] at xxxxx.common.Utilities.DataBaseConnection.openConnection(DataBaseConnection.java:53)

There is nothing you can "fix" on JMeter side, from the log file it looks like that your application server cannot connect to the database. If it's under your control - check your [JDBC URL](https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc-url-format)

In case your question is about "generating a dynamic encryption code" - you can replicate your website's password hashing logic somewhere in [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) using [Groovy language](https://groovy-lang.org/)

Reference materials:

- [Guide to the Cipher Class](https://www.baeldung.com/java-cipher-class)
- [Encryption and decryption with Groovy](https://groovy.apache.org/blog/encryption-and-decryption-with-groovy)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)